# REST webservice would not return Data of only one person entered

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, rest

I am trying to get a single Information about say a user from mssql Database using a REST api

when i call this

https://localhost:44320/api/EmployeeDB

It loads all the information with this code behind

```
    public IEnumerable<EmployeeDB> Get()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        con.Open();

        string query = "select* from [EmployeeDB].[dbo].[EmployeeTable]";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        List<EmployeeDB> empdb = new List<Models.EmployeeDB>(dt.Rows.Count);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow empdbrecord in dt.Rows)
            {
                empdb.Add(new ReadEmployee(empdbrecord));
            }
        }
        return empdb;
    }
```

This works perfectly.

Now i wanted to use the same to spool information for a Single user with this code base

```
    public IEnumerable<EmployeeDB> FetchStaffInfoByName(string Fullname) 
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        con.Open();

        string query = "select * from [EmployeeDB].[dbo].[EmployeeTable] where Fullname =" + Fullname;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        List<EmployeeDB> empdb = new List<Models.EmployeeDB>(dt.Rows.Count);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow empdbrecord in dt.Rows)
            {
                empdb.Add(new ReadEmployee(empdbrecord));
            }
        }
        return empdb;
    }
```

And running it inside Postman like this

https://localhost:44320/api/EmployeeDB?fullname=James Hall

This Fails. Rather than return only result for James Hall (For instance)only, its returning everything inside the Database,
I want to do some serious filtering in this case, kindly advice on what I must do.

Comment: did you debug the code? Looks like `FetchStaffInfoByName` code is not being executed at all.

Comment: That should give you a SQL error because Fullname is not surrounded by single quotes. This is the **exact** code?

Comment: Rename `FetchStaffInfoByName` to `Get`.

Comment: The only way you will get all the results is if the wild card % is in the string Fullname.  Also notice empdb isn't being cleared so you are adding the new results to end of old results.

Comment: Why aren't you passing `Fullname` as a proper, strongly-typed parameter? Not only does this avoid having to deal with single quotes, it also helps protect you from SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to place single quotes around your fullname property in the query (just as if you were querying it via sql):

```
"select * from [EmployeeDB].[dbo].[EmployeeTable] where Fullname = '" + Fullname + "'"";
```

I'd also recommend check out adding dynamic properties like this via parameters:
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys, Fault was actually from me, I missed few things

In case someone may need it someday, here is what my code finally Looks like, I had to rename to GET and also used the quotes around the fullname and everything responds positively.

```
public IEnumerable<EmployeeDB> Get(string Fullname) 
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    con.Open();

    string query = "select * from [EmployeeDB].[dbo].[EmployeeTable] where Fullname = '" + Fullname + "'";
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    adapter.Fill(dt);

    List<EmployeeDB> empdb = new List<Models.EmployeeDB>(dt.Rows.Count);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow empdbrecord in dt.Rows)
        {
            empdb.Add(new ReadEmployee(empdbrecord));
        }
    }
    return empdb;
}
```

Comment: But your code is still very much open to sql injection. What will happen when your variable contains a single quote? A big surprise awaits someone. Parameterize your queries!